# failed to show data in Struts2 dropdown

Tags: java, struts2

When i am making select dropdownlist using struts2 tag. I am getting following error "The requested list key 'myList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name}". 
My requirement is to retrieve the list of variable from action class and to display it in dropdown in struts2. I do need to make it as object.

```
private List<String> mylist;

public String execute(){
  mylist=new ArrayList<String>();
  mylist.add("first");
  mylist.add("second"); 
  mylist.add("third");
  setName("arun");

  return SUCCESS;
} 
public List<String> getMylist() { 
  return mylist; 
} 
public void setMylist(List<String> mylist) {
  this.mylist = mylist;
}
```

JSP:

```
<s:select label="MyList" name="myList" headerKey="-1"
    headerValue="Select Value" list="MyList" />
```

Comment: Change `list="MyList"` to `list="mylist"`.

Comment: I changed all those myList into mylist both in jsp as well as action class. But, still i am getting same error

Comment: In action? Why? Change only in JSP.

Comment: You have to change it in JSP only. `getMylist()` is read with `list="mylist"`, because the `get` part is omitted and the first letter lowercased.

Comment: Please note that SO is asynchronous, and people make comments before questions are edited.

Comment: @Arun Didn't still resolve a camelCase issue?

Comment: `synchronized (SO){//do something}`.

Comment: Interesting if a `label` is also treated as a collection? (I' m not using labels, as it requires themes)

Comment: @AleksandrM Issue got solved after i have changed the name in JSP file.. Thanks for your help. But, the real issue was, i declared getter and setter method in second action class and execute,call to second action class was mentioned in first action class. Thanks for making me to think abt getter and setter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values in struts2 dropdown in JSP, Need to initialize the list in action as given below,

```
private String mylist;

// getter and setter
```

//logic to get list like  this

```
 ShowSearch drop=new ShowSearch();
 service=drop.serviceType();  //value can be from DB or manually set in list 
setMylist(service);
```

And in JSP,

```
<s:select label="Drop" name="mylist" headerKey="-1"
    headerValue="--Select--" Value" list="mylist" />
```

Note : name used for list in jsp should be same of the initialized variable in action class.